# Не работает svg shadow

Tags: html, css3, svg

У меня возникла проблема с настройкой тени для svg с примененной к нему маской.
 jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kxnmhfL/

Ниже код:

```css
.watch-video-svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="watch-video-svg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
        <filter id="shadow">
            <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="8" stdDeviation="4"/>
        </filter>
        <mask id="cut-off-bottom">
            <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="white"/>
            <polygon points="31,20, 31,77, 80,50" fill="black"/>
            <!-- <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#Gradient)"  /> -->
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="red" mask="url(#cut-off-bottom)" filter="url(#shadow)" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Я хочу, чтобы тень появлялась только вокруг круга SVG и не содержала div.

Что может быть причиной того, почему тень не появляется?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [svg shadow does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51652185/7394871) от участника  [@sanjihan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5139911/sanjihan).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/51652185/7394871

Answer (score 2):

У SVG фильтров есть параметр -  `filter region`.
 `filter region` определяет область пикселей, которую браузер использует для хранения результатов действия фильтров. `filter region` по умолчанию - это границы элемента (к которому применяется фильтр) плюс `margin` вокруг него, чтобы позволить фильтрующим элементам, имеющим результаты, превышать размеры исходного элемента.

Однако, в вашем случае `stdDeviation` равный `4` заставляет размытие расширяться дальше, чем 10% от нормы.

Результатом является обрезанное размытие, хотя `viewBox` был увеличен достаточно, чтобы обеспечить полное размытие.

Чтобы исправить это, вам просто нужно увеличить размер области фильтра.
 Величина равная 20%, похоже, работает нормально.

```
<filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
```

Кроме того, я упростил SVG, избавившись от ненужной маски. Я также изменил `viewBox`, чтобы включить часть размытия, которая простирается влево.

```css
.watch-video-svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: linen;
}
```

```html
<div class="watch-video-svg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="-5 0 120 120">
    <defs>
        <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
            <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="8" stdDeviation="4"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" filter=url(#shadow) />
    <polygon points="31,20, 31,77, 80,50" fill="white"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [svg shadow does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51657630/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Comment: Саша а что из всего этого region ?

Comment: @MaximLensky вот это -  `<filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="120%" height="120%">`   https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#FilterEffectsRegion